# Heroku ACM fails, "CDN not returning HTTP challenge", even after I configured my DNS target

Tags: heroku, dns, hosting

I bought a domain name at domain.com, and tried to link it to my heroku app. Heroku provided me a DNS target, and I have put it through to my "DNS record" config in domain.com.

However when I try to generate automatic SSL certificate for my app, it still fails and returns me "CDN not returning HTTP challenge". I referred to this [documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/automated-certificate-management#view-your-certificate-status), it says the reason for this error is that I haven't pointed the DNS to the one provided by Heroku DNS target. But I have already done it

Is there anything I misunderstood, or do I basically have to wait for a few days for it?

[image]

Comment: PS: I know there is a free SSL service in domain.com. But when I do that, I couldn't find a way of adding it to my Heroku app, and my custom domain therefore keeps displaying "site under development"

Answer (score 0):

Under name just list it as `www.your_site.com`, [heroku](https://help.heroku.com/NH44MODG/my-root-domain-isn-t-working-what-s-wrong) says that it will forward `www.example.com` to `example.com`.

> In this case, as long as you have [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) set up, example.com
> isn't needed as users can reach your site via [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) and to
> set up [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) you need to use CNAME Records which all DNS
> Providers allow you to set.